# Disable Parent Panel, while keeping child panel enabled

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, controls, panel

I have a WinForms app, and I have a massive Panel in it. And inside that Panel is a bunch of stuff, including a second, tiny panel.

When a certain event occurs, I want the massive panel to become Enabled = false, and I still want the tiny panel to be Enabled. Can I do this? I have tried to just re-enable the tiny panel after I've disabled the massive panel, but no worky.

Or, how can I make it so the tiny panel is "on-top of", but not "inside" the massive panel?

I took a wild guess and tried:

```
tinyPanel.Parent = null;
```

and `tinyPanel.Parent = this;`

But, that just makes tinyPanel disappear.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**No, this is not possible.** *All* child controls are disabled when their parent is disabled. That's simply how Windows works; you're not going to be able to change it.

You need to find a different way of solving your problem. Re-parenting the control *is* an option, but the way you're trying to do it is incorrect. You need to remove it from the [`Controls` collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls.aspx) for the "massive Panel", and then add it to the `Controls` collection for your form. Then you will be able to change the enabled state of both controls independently.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can make a control enabled while the parent control is disabled.

Comment: Hmmm... So, maybe if I change the z-order of the tinyPanel, it may work? Or am I using my imagination too much

Comment: Z order has nothing to do with parent controls. They're orthogonal properties.

Comment: @Cody Gray: you're most likely right, I think I messed up and got it mixed up with the order of docked controls like toolstrips. Fixing my answer now