# Can you make a groupbox invisible but have it's contents visible?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

In visual basic.net I have been playing around with groupboxes and things of that nature, is there any way to group items into a box, say, buttons, and use the groupbox as a container to move / hold all of its contents while not being visible in any way?  (no decoration perhaps?)

I've tried making the groupbox invisible but that makes all the items within the groupbox invisible as well.

Comment: No. The Win32 model is very strict about this. If a parent is hidden, then all of its children are hidden as well. Why do you want to make the GroupBox invisible? Related question: [Disable Parent Panel, while keeping child panel enabled](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361340/disable-parent-panel-while-keeping-child-panel-enabled)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you really want to use is a panel, if you don't want the container to be visible (outline, etc).